# Why does my LIstBoxItem background not change

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using XAML and when I click on one of the ListBoxItems, the background changes colour as part of the controls default behavior. All I'm trying to do is change the background colour of the selected item but I can't.

I assume this has something to do with the `focusable` property and that it's overwriting my background.

My effort is (obviously this is part of a `ListBox`)

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff00ff" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The code runs but the background colour remains the default blue.

Answer (score 1):

The style give below is the default one. You need to change your desired setter.
The default setters are commented out. You can play with them. I commented the default one's and added my own. Now my selected item appears Yellow and not default blue.

[image: Selected ListBoxItem as Yellow]

Note : Just in case you don't know, you can right-click the listbox in Document Outline and see options available in "Additional Templates".

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="#FFE64747">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" OpacityMask="#FFB02626"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Yellow"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>-->
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>-->
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

...

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" >
```

[image: See additional templates in VS2012 Express for Windows Desktop]

Comment: Right clicking ListBox in the Document Outline does nothing :(

Comment: It was just for some info, you can also copy paste that style in Window.Resources and use it as it is.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions see updated answer. you can also get the same i believe in Blend.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the next way to do that:

```
<Window x:Class="SoListBoxStyleHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="StringArray" Type="system:String">
        <system:String>Examle Two</system:String>
        <system:String>Examle Three</system:String>
        <system:String>Examle Five</system:String>
        <system:String>Examle Seven</system:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource StringArray}" Background="#00FFFFFF">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DimGray"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                <Border x:Name="SimpleBackground" Visibility="Visible" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
                                <Border x:Name="OnSelectedBackground" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="Tomato" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"></ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="OnSelectedBackground" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="OnSelectedBackground" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

regards,